# ASP.NET MVC: Submit renders the same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add simple login page to ASP.NET MVC app. I actually use Sharp Arch template project. So, I added 3 methods Login(), Logout(), and DoLogin() to UsersController, where Login() just does return View("Login");

Now, when I navigate to /Users/Login, my aspx is displayed with submit button:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" Title="Login" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Orders.Web.Controllers" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
<h2>Login</h2>
    <% if (ViewContext.TempData["message"] != null){ %>
        <p><%= ViewContext.TempData["message"]%></p>
    <% } %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm<UsersController>(u => u.DoLogin()))
       { %>
            <div><% =Html.SubmitButton("submit") %></div>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

However, when I click Submit, request is made once again to Login() - I can see it when I set breakpoint there, it doesn't try to go to UsersController.DoLogin() even though in resulting HTML page form has action /Users/DoLogin. When I manually enter /Users/DoLogin in browser, it gets called and my breakpoint gets fired.

I'm banging my head for few hours already... I don't see whats wrong here.

Comment: Can you post the produced HTML? ie, render the page and "View Source"

Comment: Well, thank you very much ;-) I _did_ inspect then sources but when I started prettifying it to post, I found this:
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Login" id="aspnetForm">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNzk5NTAxODI0ZGRZT7ztWfhzWzpYD2732UhN/MPAwQ==" />
And then I realized this in my site.master:
<form id="form1" runat="server">
Seems that when I opened .master in VS2008 editor and tried to add menu, it added an ASP.NET form... which wrapped my MVC form and got in the way.
Removing this extra form solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so thanks to jamesshannon I found that this was because my site.master page suddenly wrapped everything into an ASP.NET form - probably because I edited it using VS2008 editor. Not sure if such behavior is very nice but... now I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

Must be a routing issue. Can you paste your routes, you could also try [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) route debugger

Comment: OK I tried the debugger, /Users/Login and /Users/DoLogin both route to appropriate controller/action... actually both /Users/Login and /Users/DoLogin works as expected when typed into URL in browser. It's the submit button that seems to fail to work...